# проблема c Fullpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал сайт и добавил в него библиотеку Fullpage.Проблема в следующем,при разрешении 16:9 все нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть,когда ширина намного больше,чем высота то все хорошо.Но когда высота практически равна ширине то весь контент уходит вверх.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].У блока высота 100vh,сверстал все в единицах vw.

Comment: Я не понял. Вы задали высоту в 100vh и при этом вас удивляет, что контейнер растянут по ширине видимой области?

Comment: Лучше уточните, как должен вести себя контент на втором скрине.

Comment: должен оставаться на том же месте

Comment: Так контент на том же месте и остается. Растягивается вниз родитель, по высоте экрана.